# combined multiple tensorflow dataset?

Tags: tensorflow

i have image dataset that i apply couple augmentation methods and create a separate dataset for each method, then i concatenate all datasets to one and used in CNN, however i am getting this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args)
    415             attrs=("executor_type", executor_type,
    416                    "config_proto", config),
--> 417             ctx=ctx)
    418       # Replace empty list with None
    419       outputs = outputs or None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     if any(ops._is_keras_symbolic_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [100352,3] and labels shape [32]
     [[{{node loss/dense_1_loss/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_2206]
```

code:

```
path_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train)
label_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.cast(y_train, tf.int64))
image_train_ds = path_train_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

image_label_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_train_ds, label_train_ds))

def random_flip_up_down(img,label):
    tf_img = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(img,1)
    return tf_img,label

image_label_train_random_flip_up_down=image_label_train_ds.map(random_flip_up_down)

def random_saturation(img,label):
    tf_img = tf.image.random_saturation(img,0.3,0.8,1)
    return tf_img,label

image_label_train_random_saturation =image_label_train_ds.map(random_saturation)

def concet(ds):
  ds0 = ds[0]
  for ds1 in ds[1:]:
     ds0 = ds0.concatenate(ds1)
  return ds0    

ds =[image_label_train_random_flip_up_down,image_label_train_random_saturation]
image_label_ds_aug = concet(ds)
model_4.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history_4 = model_4.fit(image_label_ds_aug, epochs=8, steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(10000/BATCH_SIZE),
validation_data=(image_label_test_ds),callbacks = [MetricsCheckpoint('logs')])
```

Comment: It's unclear how you create your dataset. This error message can be caused by many things

Comment: @Sharky it is tensorflow dataset i created from list of images paths and  pass it as argument to  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices. i updated my question to include this step

Comment: First of all, you doesn't batch your dataset. Apply `.batch()` to `concet(ds)`. Why do you need so many separate augmentation function, while it could be easily done in a single map? `concet` function is doing smth strange. Please take a look at how input pipeline should be organized. I think you're just overcomplicating things

Comment: @Sharky   i only have 300 images, so i thought by applying separate augmentation i can increase my dataset size. so if i used just one map does these will produce a separate image for each augmentation method

Comment: You just pack all these functions into one. It's simply much cleaner and will allow you to upsample your dataset. I'd advise you to read https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets, rewrite your code and you'll find what causes error in no time